# How can I add a new row to the list when I press the button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input, button and when this button is pressed it adds a new row to the table list. I get such an array from API. Only the first 8 of this array are good for me. I got the first 8 of them with the slice method.  I have read some posts about this but could not understand. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by you can not what type ou structure tout use ?! what is is problème exactly tout help !? édit it before stackoverflow experts come ans start downvoting ..

Answer (score 0):

You could try this I don't know if it answers your question

```
let arr = [], // contains the 40 entries
    newArray = [];

arr.map((item) => {
  if(newArray.length <= 7){
     return newArray.push(item);
  }
}); 
console.log(newArray) // array with 8 entries
```

and adding a new row

```
const createRow = (dt, main, weather, clouds, wind) => {
   return newArray.push({dt, main, weather, clouds, wind});
}
```

call createRow with args

```
createRow("20/02/2021 18:51",{...}, "cloudy","120 knots")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want the first eight element of an array?

```
const arraysample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

const firstEight = (array) => {
  let eight = [];
  arraysample.forEach((obj, i) => {
    if (i < 8) {
      eight.push(obj);
    }
  })
  return eight;
};

console.log(firstEight(arraysample))
```

Comment: No, I take the first 8 elements, but I don't know how to dynamically add rows by adding this to the previous state. I have a table with 8 heads.

Comment: You can push an item directly in the state using : 
addInArrayState = (item) => {
    this.setState({youroldstate: [...this.state.menu, item] })
  }